# I am not getting select fields value

Tags: jquery, html

here is my html page. I am not getting the value of select tag. It was working till I hadn't added the select tag. But now its not working.

```
<form id="multi">  
    <div>
        <label>Tag</label>
        <select name="" class="tag">
            <option value="1">India</option>
            <option value="2">Australia</option>
        </select>
        <input class="tag" type="text" name="" value="text" />
        <a href="#" data-action="add">add</a>
        <a href="#" data-action="delete">delete</a>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="save" >
</form>
```

and jquery function is

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var multiTags = $("#multi");
    function handler(e) 
        var jqEl = $(e.currentTarget);
        var tag = jqEl.parent();
        switch (jqEl.attr("data-action")) {
        case "add":
            tag.after(tag.clone().find("input","select").val("").end());
            break;
        case "delete":
            tag.remove();
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function save(e) {
        var tags = multiTags.find("input.tag","select.tag").map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get().join(',');
        alert(tags);
        return false;
    }

    multiTags.submit(save).find("a").live("click", handler);
});
```

Comment: When you say, *"I am not getting select fields value"*, do you mean that you're not getting these values when you submit the form?

Comment: obviously...After submitting the form

Comment: You have forgotten the open braces for handler function. `function handler(e) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` does not take two arguments. use `find('input.tag, select.tag')`instead. `find('.tag')`suffices too.

Answer (score 0):

`find` does not work with multiple selectors.

simply use

```
.find(".tag")
```

[Here's a simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66FMD/)

Answer (score -1):

You're not getting the values of your `select` element because it's missing a `name` attribute.

Obviously.

```
<select name="I-HAVE-A-NAME-THEREFORE-I-EXIST" class="tag"></select>
```

This has nothing to do with JavaScript or jQuery.